# Detecting the device upside down

Tags: iphone, uiaccelerometer

what are the correct values for detecting the device upside down?

I have the following and it starts detecting when the user has titled the device on its back.

I use the following values

```
float xx = -[acceleration x];
    float yy = [acceleration y];
    float angle = atan2(yy, xx);

    if(angle >= 0.75 && angle <= 2.25)
    {
        NSLog(@"Upside down");
    }
```

Comment: Don't try to reinvent the wheel here. This is documented in the UIDevice API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start listening for orientation events by using:

```
UIDevice *currDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[currDevice beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Then, get the orientation using:

```
currDevice.orientation
```

These are the values that are returned:

{'1' : 'Portrait',
                                 '2' : 'PortraitUpsideDown',
                                 '3' : 'LandscapeLeft',
                                 '4' : 'LandscapeRight',
                                 '5' : 'FaceUp',
                                 '6' : 'FaceDown'}

Comment: so in your case, you'd want to listen for when currDevice.orientation is 6

Comment: I had to get the orientation == 2. Thanks, this helped me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

[UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

See 'Getting the Device Orientation' part.

Answer (score 0):

this is my approach (with code) to implement device orientations handling on iOS, and you can use it if you like:

[How to handle UIDeviceOrientation for manage views layouts](http://www.littleaps.com/littleAps_Software/littleBlog/Entradas/2011/6/16_How_to_handle_UIDeviceOrientation_for_manage_views_layouts.html)